# Jenkins installed via docker cannot run on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I'm new to devops. I want to install Jenkins in AWS EC2 with docker.

I have installed the Jenkins by this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

On AWS security group, I have enabled port 8080 and 50000. I also enabled port 22 for SSH, 27017 for Mongo and 3000 for Node.

I can see the Jenkins container when I run `docker ps`. However, when I run `https://xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`, there is not a Jenkins window popup for Jenkins setting and display error, ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Does someone know what's wrong here? Should I install `Nginx` as well? I didn't install it yet.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, but non-was accepted. If all the answers weren't useful, that's fine. But if the answers were helpful, they acceptance is not only a good practice, but it signals others in future with similar issues to solve their own issues. Also it reduces the amount of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you are using https:

```
https://xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

From your description it does not seem that you've setup any type of ssl connection to your instance. So you should connect using http only:

```
http://xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

But this is **not good practice** as you communicate using plain text. A common solution is to access your jenkins web-ui through **ssh tunnel**. This way the connection is encrypted and you don't have to exposed any jenkins port in your security groups.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's working with http. I didn't notice it's with https when copy it from AWS IP address. Thank you. 

When you say it's not a good practice in this way, do you mean I should change the docker command or the docker command is fine but I should use other softwares to make Jenkins connected?